# Opendir error; No such file or directory found

Tags: php, image, src, opendir

This may be a very easy question. I am working in directory /mobile and I have photos in a directory /uploads.

I am getting the error:

`Warning: opendir(http://www.yoozpaper.com/uploads) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: not implemented in /hermes/bosweb/web088/b881/ipg.yoozpapercom/mobile/sportspage.php on line 313`

I am putting this into a variable $dir = `"http://www.yoozpaper.com/uploads"`

for the image `src=$dir/$file`.

Note that this is working when I am working with files in the main directory.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Code below:

```
$dir = "http://www.yoozpaper.com/uploads";
```

//open directory

```
if ($opendir = opendir($dir))
{
```

//read directory

```
while (($file = readdir($opendir)) !==FALSE)
{

if ($file==$imagename)
```

//can specify height and width below

```
echo "<img width='75%' height='30%' src='$dir/$file' title='$headline - Yoozpaper News Online' alt='$headline'><br /><br />";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to understand the difference between *a filesystem* and an *HTTP daemon*.
Although they have somewhat similar appearance, it is absolutely different matters.

To use opendir, you have to open **a directory*, not HTTP resource.

```
opendir('../uploads');
```

should work

```
opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads');
```

would be better as it will always point to the uploads directory, no matter from where you called it.

Comment: Thank you. Used opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads');

Answer (score 1):

http://www.yoozpaper.com/uploads us a URL not a directory. You can't access it using opendir. You need the system path to it for example "/home/user/public_html/uploads" or something. Get the path to the directory using your file manager or control panel

It might "/hermes/bosweb/web088/b881/" in your case. m not sure though. In any case, get the local path