# Can not opendir() network unit in php

Tags: php, networking, opendir

> I need to open a directory on my php application.
>
> My machine has *Windows XP*, the unit i need to access is a shared
>   folder that is of the      server, and is mapped on my PC as the
>   *"G:"* unit.
>
> I have already entered the user name and password and saved them, so
>   that when my PC boots I can enter the unit "G" without doing anything.
>   The server has *Windows Server 2008*.

My code:

```
$path = 'G:\LABORATORIO2\Repositorio';

$dir = opendir($path);
```

I get the next error :

```
Warning: opendir(G:\LABORATORIO2\Repositorio) [function.opendir]: 
failed to open dir: No such file or directory in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\REPOHCL\laboratProtocolos.php on line 160
```

If i paste the address `G:\LABORATORIO2\Repositorio` on my file explorer, it opens perfectly.

If I change the address for an address that points to my local drive, go perfectly.

Comment: Check the folder permissions!

Comment: The folder is a test folder i just created, doesn's have any permissions.

Comment: Ok, check this, maybe it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155992/opendir-error-no-such-file-or-directory-found

Comment: Have you read the comments on the manpage about using opendir on windows network drives? http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php

Comment: Erman, it doesn't work because the folder i need to open is not inside the root of my application